# Reading data from Java DataInputStream in Matlab for fast communication of large amounts of data

Tags: java, matlab

I am trying to read data over TCP into matlab using Java classes.  Everything I have seen online for this uses the java.io.DataInputStream.readbyte() method to pull data from the tcp datastream into matlab.  This is much, much too slow (by a factor of about 1000) for the very large amounts of data I am trying to stream.

I imagine that using the java.io.DataInputStream.read(byte b[]) method would be much faster.  However, I can't seem to coerce it to work.

For example, I am trying the following to create the java byte array in matlab

```
jbytes = javaArray('java.lang.Byte',8)
```

I then create a DataInputStream object and try to use the read method

```
dataInputStream.read(jbytes)
```

And I get the error:

No method 'read' with matching signature found for class 'java.io.DataInputStream'

Based on the Matlab documentation, it seems like I should be able to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: After looking at this, there is no real solution.  Just the process of converting from a javaArray to a matlab array is outrageously time consuming.  In fact, you are much better off writing to a file in Java and then reading a file into matlab rather than trying to convert a million bytes between the two.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is created 9 years ago, but maybe my solution will help others.

I wrote a small wrapper class to read all available byte to a public buffer.

```
public class ByteInputStream extends java.io.FilterInputStream
{
  public byte[] Buffer = new byte[65536];
  
  public ByteInputStream(java.io.InputStream IS)
  {
    super(IS);
  }

  public int readAll() throws java.io.IOException
  {
    return this.read(Buffer);
  }
}
```

After this file is compiled with javac you can us it in Matlab like:

```
Socket = java.net.Socket('127.0.0.1', 123);
SocketIn = this.Socket.getOutputStream();
SocketOut = ByteInputStream(this.Socket.getInputStream());
if SocketOut.available() > 0
  NumBytes = SocketOut.readAll();
  Buffer = Socket.Buffer(1:NumBytes);
  disp(Buffer);
end
```

Comment: Your `readAll` method is a bit of a misnomer since it only reads up to 65536 bytes and it appears that the OP is trying to read a lot more bytes than that. So I'm not sure how much your _solution will help others_.

Comment: Thanks @Abra for your comment. You can call the function readAll multiple times until it returns 0. Then the buffer is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try byte [] jbytes = new byte[8];
Byte class is a wrapper for the primitive byte which is the required argument for DataInpuStream.read(byte []).

Comment: jbytes has to be declared within matlab, so that the data can be passed directly into matlab.  So I guess this question comes down to how to declare a java array in matlab that contains a java primitive.